# Powershell: how to read an environment variable?

Tags: powershell

This is the first powershell script I have attempted. When I run it, part one runs fine and creates the log.txt, but after running it again it still runs part 1. How can I check if the log file exists??

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I am running the script from PowerShell ISE if that makes a difference.

```
#Variables.
#Set working directory to scripts location.
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath

#Check if log file exists.
$ChkFile = "%userprofile%\Desktop\log.txt" 
$FileExists = (Test-Path $ChkFile -PathType Leaf)

#Set dir to script location.
Set-Location $dir

#Part 1.
If (!($FileExists)) 
{
    Write-Host "Part 1"
    echo 0 >>log.txt
}
#Part 2.
ElseIf ($FileExists)
{
    Write-Host "Part 2"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%` is for cmd.exe variable expansion. You need a different syntax for PowerShell. Instead use:

```
 "$env:userprofile\Desktop\log.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. Do all cmd.exe commands not work in powershell?

Comment: @AndrewRynhard  If the command is implemented with cmd.exe then it will not work in PowerShell unless you invoke it via `& cmd.exe /c <DOS COMMAND HERE>`. If the command is actually a command line program like `xcopy` it will work fine in PowerShell.

Comment: Andy is spot on for *commands*, but the percent (%) indicator falls under a different, though like-minded, rule: if the *feature* is implemented by cmd.exe then you must find the analogous feature in PowerShell. In this instance, `%xyz%` indicates an environment variable under cmd.exe, while `$env:xyz` indicates the same env var in PowerShell.

Comment: @msorens Actually you can pass in cmd.exe operators. Try these: `& cmd.exe /c echo '%userprofile%\Desktop\log.txt'` and `& cmd.exe /c dir '"%ProgramFiles%"' '&' dir '"%windir%"'`. They just get sent as strings to cmd.exe which evaluates them at runtime.